# how do i change my background image when my mouse hovers over a button in a dropdown menu using javascript function?

Tags: html, jquery, css, mouseevent, onmouseover

This is the code for my HTML page and I'm trying to create a photography site. I was planning to create a website in which when a person hovers over a button on the menu section the background will show the image related to that section, for eg. I've tried for animal button here. But the HTML page is not responsive.
I want the image to be displayed on the whole webpage in the background.

I'm a beginner in Javascript Html and CSS.

Kindly help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Our First Photography Site</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   //
   function animals() 
   { 
     $('#animals').hover(function() {
     $(this).attr('src', 'https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/2019/10/wildlife-photographer- 
     of-the-year-2019/#/05-wildlife-awards-audun-rikardsen---wildlife-photographer-of-the-year.jpg');
     }, function() {
     $(this).attr('src', 'https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/2019/10/wildlife-photographer- 
     of-the-year-2019/#/11-wildlife-awards-max-waugh---wildlife-photographer-of-the-year.jpg');
     });
}
//  
 </script>   
</head>
<body>
<nav>
     <div class="menu">
        <button class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
        <div class="menu-content">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
        <a href="animal.html" id="animals">Animals</a>
        <a href="travel.html" id="travel">Travel</a>
        <a href="food.html" id="food">Food</a>
        </div>
      </div>  
</nav>  
<br>
</body>
</html>

<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.menu-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.menu:hover .menu-content {display: block;}

.menu:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}

 </style>
```

Comment: Do you need to change the image of the whole page or is this an image inside the menu ?

Comment: I want the image to be displayed on the whole webpage in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? When using jQuery, make sure you import the cdn or library to your html, and put all of your jQuery code within a document ready code like so:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ YOUR CODE HERE });
```

Another error in your code is that you shouldn't be using the "src" attribute with your jQuery. Remember that "this" is referring to "#animals", which is a link not an image. If you want to change the background image, you would want to change the css property "background-image" instead.

The image urls you were using weren't working so I used some stock images so you can see the code working. Make sure that your urls lead to an image, not a site. Your urls look like they are leading to a site.

In your CSS I also added

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
```

to all of your links (#animals, #travel and #food). The background-size property determines how your image covers its container. Using "cover" makes it so the image always fills the width of its container, and any excess height is not seen. Background-position determines what part of the image is displayed. By default, it would be the top left. I changed it to center so you can see the focus of the images. The "transition" property is completely optional, it makes it so that the images transition on hover within 0.3s. It just serves to make the background change smoother and not suddenly jump between images.

I don't know if you wanted the image when you are not hovering to show so I specifically declared the initial background image url in the '#animals' css as well. If you don't want it to show an image until after a user hovers, you can remove this line from the CSS. Otherwise, if you want it to show an initial image make sure you declare the background-image for each link separately.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Our First Photography Site</title>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#animals').hover(
       function() {
       $(this).css('background-image','url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504208434309-cb69f4fe52b0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80)');
       },
       function() {
       $(this).css('background-image','url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501706362039-c06b2d715385?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2035&q=80)');
       }
      )
   })
  </script>   
</head>
<body>
<nav>
     <div class="menu">
        <button class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
        <div class="menu-content">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
        <a href="animal.html" id="animals">Animals</a>
        <a href="travel.html" id="travel">Travel</a>
        <a href="food.html" id="food">Food</a>
        </div>
      </div>  
</nav>  
<br>
</body>
</html>

<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.menu-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.menu:hover .menu-content {display: block;}

.menu:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}

#animals, #travel, #food {
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}

#animals {
background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501706362039-c06b2d715385?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2035&q=80);
}

 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code :

- you declare a function but you never call it
- you are using jQuery but I can't see any jquery import
- your function is targetting your link and not a section

I suggest you use vanilla javascript and event delegation :

```js
let page = document.querySelector('.page');
let menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

const changeBg = (event) => {
    let target = event.target.closest('a');
    if (target && target.dataset.image) {
      page.style.backgroundImage = `url(${target.dataset.image})`;
   }
}

menu.addEventListener('mouseover', event => changeBg(event));
menu.removeEventListener('mouseover', event => changeBg(event));
```

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.menu ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/" data-image="https://placekitten.com/200/300">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" data-image="https://placekitten.com/300/300">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" data-image="https://placekitten.com/280/300">Test</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
  <section class="page" style="background-image: url('')">
    PAGE
  </section>
</div>
```